# Python: Getting current page url while turning next pages

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, getcurrenturl

I'm witting Python script which extract current page url by going to next page, and extract page url.

I can confirm that the browser is up and connecting to start page. But after that, Nothing will happen.

e.g)
start page:

```
`https://www.jtb.co.jp/kokunai-hotel/list/kyoto/feature/couple_yado/?multiarea=26&dateunspecified=1&page=1`
```

URL I want extract is following 4 pages:

`・https://www.jtb.co.jp/kokunai-hotel/list/kyoto/feature/couple_yado/?multiarea=26&dateunspecified=1&page=1`

`・https://www.jtb.co.jp/kokunai-hotel/list/kyoto/feature/couple_yado/?multiarea=26&dateunspecified=1&page=2`

`・https://www.jtb.co.jp/kokunai-hotel/list/kyoto/feature/couple_yado/?multiarea=26&dateunspecified=1&page=3`

`・https://www.jtb.co.jp/kokunai-hotel/list/kyoto/feature/couple_yado/?multiarea=26&dateunspecified=1&page=4`

I wrote script as below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
import time

 
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path',options=options)


pageURL = 'https://www.jtb.co.jp/kokunai-hotel/list/kyoto/feature/couple_yado/'
driver.get(pageURL)
sleep(3)


elem_urls = []


while True:
    url = driver.current_url
    
    for urls in url:
        elem_urls.append(urls)
    
    try:
        next_button = driver.find_elemenent_by_class_name('f-list-paging__next')
        next_button.click()
        sleep(3)
        
    except Exception:
        break
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? What's going wrong when you execute this?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

when I starts this script, I can confirm that the browser is up and running.
But after that, Nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the links for the pages you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.jtb.co.jp/kokunai-hotel/list/kyoto/feature/couple_yado/')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.f-list-paging-num__link")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.jtb.co.jp/kokunai-hotel/list/kyoto/feature/couple_yado/')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'f-list-paging-num__link')]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://www.jtb.co.jp/kokunai-hotel/list/kyoto/?page=1', 'https://www.jtb.co.jp/kokunai-hotel/list/kyoto/?page=2', 'https://www.jtb.co.jp/kokunai-hotel/list/kyoto/?page=3', 'https://www.jtb.co.jp/kokunai-hotel/list/kyoto/?page=4']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```